# Get average of time spent using std::chrono

Tags: c++, average, duration, c++-chrono

I have a function running more than a million times. I want to print out the duration of how long the function takes to run by printing the sum of durations of 10,000 calls to the function.

At the start of each function I have something like this:

```
int counter = 0;
auto duration_total = 0; //not sure about the type
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1, t2, duration;

t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); 
Function f(){
  counter++;
}

t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
duration= std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
duration_total += duration;

if(counter %10000 == 0){
      long int average_duration = duration_total/10000;
      duration_total = 0;
      cout << average_duration << "\n";
}
```

I can't find a way to add durations and then get their average.

Comment: I basically want to have something like that. But the problem is that I can't add the duration to any int or primitive data type as their is a type mismatch. I am also not able to find how to achieve this with existing duration operators.

Comment: Here's a chrono video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M  It's about an hour and I encourage you to watch all of it.  However at the 43:28 mark it specifically covers the mistake in algebra that you are making, which is the cause of your compile-time error.  `chrono` is all about catching your mistakes at compile-time, so that once you get things to compile, run-time errors are far less likely.

Comment: Thanks I'll watch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [`std::chrono::duration<Rep,Period>::count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/count), you can see that you can use

```
int duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
```

(or something else, e.g., `unsigned long`), as the return value is

> The number of ticks for this duration.

in full:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    auto duration_total = 0; //not sure about the type
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1, t2;

    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); 

    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    int duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
    duration_total += duration;

    if(counter %10000 == 0){
          long int average_duration = duration_total/10000;
          duration_total = 0;
          std::cout << average_duration << "\n";
    }
}
```

See it in [Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0d7478934ef00a4).

Comment: A better style would be to stay within the chrono type system while doing the averaging and only escape when you absolutely have to.  Namely at the print statement:  `std::cout << average_duration.count() <<  "ns\n";`  This suggested style allows the compiler check your duration algebra for logic mistakes, and emit an error if you accidentally make one (not that you did in this case).  In C++20 you won't even have to escape the type system at the print statement:  `std::cout << average_duration <<  "\n";`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Thanks! I'll check out more the C++20 type system.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Yeah I was wondering about type safety. Other links suggest not moving out. In my case though.

Answer (score 2):

You create a clock when you start and one when you stop.
When subtracting one clock from another, you get a duration. Divide the duration with the number of iterations.

Example:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
auto timeit(size_t iterations, std::function<void()> func_to_test) {
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for(size_t i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
        func_to_test();

    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    return std::chrono::duration_cast<T>(end - start) / iterations;
}

int main() {
    auto dur =
        timeit<std::chrono::microseconds>(10000, [] { system("echo Hello World"); });

    std::cout << dur.count() << " µs\n";
}
```

If you need to sum up individual runs, keep a duration variable that you add to. I'm reusing the same `timeit` function, but you can remove the `iteration` stuff in it if you only want to run it once.

```
int main() {
    std::chrono::microseconds tot{0};
    size_t iterations = 0;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        // sum up the total time spent
        tot += timeit<decltype(tot)>(1, [] { system("echo Hello World"); });
        ++iterations;
    }
    // divide with the number of iterations
    std::cout << (tot / iterations).count() << " µs\n";
}
```

Comment: It won't work in my case. I have a thread that is calling this function and am summing up the timings that the thread is using this function live. I can't iterate through it like that.

Comment: @Hadi The principle is the same. Added example.

Comment: Upvoted for staying within the chrono type system until the print statement.  Best (safest) style!

Comment: @HowardHinnant Thanks - it's nice to hear that from the time master himself :-)

Answer (score 1):

First, the type here is int:

```
auto duration_total = 0;
```

You should do something similar to it:

```
auto t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
//do some work
auto t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
double duration_in_seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(t2 - t1).count();
```

Note that I'm casting the duration to double. Then you can use the duration value more freely.

If you prefer nanoseconds:

```
double duration_in_nanoseconds =  std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
```